# How to declare object literal as Record with implicit keys

Tags: typescript

If a constant object literal is created without declaring a type, it will infer the keys from the value:

```
const OBJ = {foo: 42, bar: 42}
```

This will become a `Record<'foo' | 'bar', number>`, which means IDEs will be helpful to offer auto-completion when typing `OBJ.fo` etc.

If the same object is declared like this:

```
const OBJ: Record<string, number> = {foo: 42, bar: 42}
```

then IDEs will pretend not to know that `OBJ` has keys `foo` and `bar`, since `OBJ` is a record of *any* string key. :(

Now, if the values are simple primitives, omitting the type and relying on implicit inferred types usually works fine, but if the record is more complex, such as a `Record<string, MyEnum>` or `Record<string, (x: string, y: number) => number>` etc, doing so will lose the type information of the *values*:

```
enum MyEnum {
  A = 42,
  B = 85
}

const OBJ = {foo: A, bar: B};
```

Now `OBJ` will be a `Record<'foo' | 'bar', number>`, *not* a `Record<'foo' | 'bar', MyEnum>`.

What I want is to declare a dictionary where the type of the values is given in the declaration, but keys are inferred.

The only ways I've found are:

1. Type each *value*

```
const OBJ = {foo: <MyEnum>A, bar: <MyEnum>B};
```

2. Declare keys separately

```
type Keys = 'foo' | 'bar';
const OBJ: Record<Keys, MyEnum> = {foo: A, bar: B};
```

Is there a better way, where the keys are inferred by the literal but the values are declared on the entire `Record`?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure which TypeScript version you are using. Also, your example has an error, you need to use `MyEnum.A` instead of just `A`.

Let's look at your example:

```
enum MyEnum {
  A = 42,
  B = 85
}

const OBJ = {foo: MyEnum.A, bar: MyEnum.B};
```

`OBJ` has the correct type: `{ foo: MyEnum; bar: MyEnum; }`. Tested in `3.9 >` typescript.

Try on [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=3.9.7&ssl=6&ssc=19&pln=6&pc=25#code/KYOwrgtgBAsgngUXNA3gWAFBSgQSgXigBYAmAGk2wCECoAOAVkwF9NMBjAexAGcAXKAHkqAKVooAZp04AuWImQA6HGSgAjAIYAnOfCSRFVZgG42GPnAAOweYLUArWheucJQ0UA)

---

Regarding your requirements:

> What I want is to declare a dictionary where the type of the values is given in the declaration, but keys are inferred.

You can use [Generics function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) to infer type:

```
enum MyEnum {
  A = 42,
  B = 85
}

function fixType<T extends string>(value: Record<T, MyEnum>): Record<T, MyEnum> {
  return value
}

const OBJ = fixType({foo: MyEnum.A, bar: MyEnum.B})
```

And now `OBJ` has `Record<"foo" | "bar", MyEnum>` type.

Try on [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=3.9.7#code/KYOwrgtgBAsgngUXNA3gWAFBSgQSgXigBYAmAGk2wCECoAOAVkwF9NMAzMEAYwBcBLAPYgo7fgA8AKnAAOwADySowcb1AATAM5RNvAE78QAcwB8ACgBuAQwA2YYAC4oAJWDdBe9YrKxEyEwCUTq7unt6%20SJAmUOhYUHrAvGB6ItZ2wCxsGO4gulAA8lQAUrRiUrLAZijsgoJO8JEQAHQ4PgBGVnr1fpBNVMwBQA)

---

If you are using `Enum`, you may be interested in [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/32690#issuecomment-647586392). To sum up, even if you specified which numbers your enum supports, TS still allows assigning any number...